# Discord.py. Как отслеживать тех, кто ведет стримы на сервере или общается по видеосвязи?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Искал в рекомендации ивенты на старт стримов или видеосвязи, планировал вычитать время старта из времени окончания. Но по итогу план провалился т.к банально не нашел ивенты подходящие под задачу.

Comment: Никак, библиотека не поддерживает такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я недавно задавал воспрос разработчикам (Практически такой же).
Ответ:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта информация недоступна боту.